# Spark Scala sum of values by unique key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

If I have key,value pairs that compromise item(key) and the sales(value):

```
bolt 45
bolt 5
drill 1
drill 1
screw 1
screw 2
screw 3
```

So I want to obtain an RDD where each element is the sum of the values for every unique key:

```
bolt 50
drill 2
screw 6
```

My current code is like that:

```
val salesRDD = sc.textFile("/user/bigdata/sales.txt")
val pairs = salesRDD.map(s => (s, 1))
val counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
counts.collect().foreach(println)
```

But my results get this:

```
(bolt 5,1)
(drill 1,2)
(bolt 45,1)
(screw 2,1)
(screw 3,1)
(screw 1,1)
```

How should I edit my code to get the above result?

Comment: What is the point of `pairs` ? Why are you mapping to a tuple in the first place ?

Comment: @sinanspd then how do I go about to get my desired results? :)

Comment: You didn't answer my question. If you are putting a set value like `1` in your code it has to have a meaning. You aren't reading the data correctly. It seems like the data is not comma delimited but uses spaces. So you will have to split the read lines in order to get a tuple of `(item, sales)`. Right now you have a list of `(string, 1)` pairs, where both the item and the sales are stored in the string, so when you try to reduce, the keys don't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java way, hope you can convert this to scala. Looks like you just need a groupby and count

```
  salesRDD.groupBy(salesRDD.col("name")).count();


+-----+-----+
| name|count|
+-----+-----+
| bolt|   50|
|drill|    2|
|screw|   6 |
+-----+-----+
```

Also,
please use Datasets and Dataframes rather than RDDs. You will find it a lot handy